# Geocoder - Convert Coordinates to Country and City

Tags: javascript, html, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to convert longitude and latitude coordinates into country and city for users. Currently, I am using an API from darkskynet to query the coordinates. I'm not sure if I'm thinking of it properly, but I wanted to convert the coordinates to country name and city name by using the coordinates to query and convert my coordinates. Any advice or hints are greatly appreciated. If there's another way of getting this information, I would gladly appreciate any suggestions.Forgive me for my poor nesting. Thanks in advance for suggesting. Below is a copy of my code:

```js
function weather() {
  function success(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    location.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + latitude + "°" + "Longitude: " + longitude + '°';
    var theUrl = url + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longtitude + "?callback=?";


    $.getJSON(theUrl, function(data) {
      $("#temp").html(data.currently.temperature);
      $("#minutely").html(data.minutely.summary)

      function getWeather(latitude, longitude) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=AIzaSyBpiTf5uzEtJsKXReoOKXYw4RO0ayT2Opc',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(results) {
            $("#city").text(results.adress_components.long_name)
            $("#country").text(results.sys.country)
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  var location = document.getElementById("location");
  var apiKey = "3827754c14ed9dd9c84afdc4fc05a1b3";
  var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
  location.innerHTML = "Locating...";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  weather();
})
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale = 1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src=h ttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js></script>
</head>



<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <div id="temp"></div>
      <div id="minutely" id="tempunit"></div>
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <div id="location"></div>
    </h2>
  </header>
  <p><span id="city" </span><span id="country"></span></p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="BT1">Change Metric</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you activated your JS Google API?

Comment: `h ttps` << what's that? Why you placed `app.js` up there? ... So many errors...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **[activated you JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)** and try with

```js
var Geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

function geocodeLatLng(latlng, cb) {
  return Geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function(res, status) {
    return cb((status === 'OK') ? (res[1] || "Nothing found") : status);
  });
}


// The ones you get from weather
var coordinates = {
  lat: 45.8150,
  lng: 15.9819
}

geocodeLatLng(coordinates, function(data) {
  console.log(data.address_components[0].long_name); // City
  console.dir(data.address_components[2].long_name); // Country
});
```

```html
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
```